# Typescript: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | { value: string; label: string; }'

Tags: typescript

Getting this error,

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | { value: string; label: string; }'.
```

when we have this OR operator, it should be able to take any values right? so if the value is string, then it should be fine, shouldn’t it?

Comment: add more context : what code provoque this error. This | operator enables you to have an object being something or some other thing. Given that if you do console.log(myObject.value) with myObject behing a string. then this is normal :)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types